# how to store custom plugin data to database without using custom table in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I am developing a wordpress plugin , where I need to store some custom data to database . 
Custom data what I want to store like "class title" , "numeric name of class (it will be an integer value) " . Site admin could add those data every time he wants.

To get those data from site admin I have created a form. But I am having problem while storing those data to database . I dont want to use custom table . So I used options api for store those data . I used this function to store data

```
    add_option('class_title', $class_title);
    add_option('class_numeric', $class_numeric);
```

But using this method , user could add data to database only once . But I need to store data more than one time with same option name (in this case ,'class_title' and 'class_numeric').

How could I able to store those custom data to database with same option name  more than one time using options api or any other way without custom table. If there are not any other way , then I will use custom table .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a post type, but you could also serialize your option, ie. storing it as an array of array

```
myoptions = array (
 0 => array ('class_title' =>$class_title, 'class_numeric'=>$class_numeric ) ,
 1 => array ('class_title' =>$class_title, 'class_numeric'=>$class_numeric ) );
```

Depending of what you want to achieve, both solutions have their advantages. The second one would be better from a performance point of view.

Comment: thanks for comment .I have tried 2nd one,and it works , but not 100% .By trying your solution I could add multiple values , but only once . I need to add more than one time with multiple values.

I used this code,

add_option('class_details', $myoptions);

. Should I use update_option() ??

Comment: I have solved this problem . I used this code

$myoptions = array (
        array ('class_title' =>$class_title, 'class_numeric'=>$class_numeric) ,
         );

        if( !get_option( 'class_details' ) ) {

            add_option('class_details', $myoptions);

        }
    else{
        $arrays_class_detail=get_option( 'class_details' );
        $marge_array=array_merge($arrays_class_detail,$myoptions);
        update_option('class_details',$marge_array);
    }

Answer (score 1):

I think an easy way would be to add a [post type](http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types#Custom_Post_Types).

> WordPress 3.0 gives you the capability to add your own custom post types and to use them in different ways.